# Finding the most frequent contestant on survivor without duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop-duplicates

Trying to find the most frequent contestant on the game show survivor but need to drop the duplicates of contestants that might have been in the same season (if they entered back in the same season that doesn't count)

The `castaways` dataframe is sorted by

- season name,
- season,
- castaway id,
- full name,
- season,
- etc.

The `castaway_details` dataframe has the information

- castaway id,
- full name,
- gender,
- etc.

I use the `castaway` dataframe to count the number of times a contestant was on a season of survivor, however, i want to remove if that contestant was on the same season multiple times.

```
castaway_details[castaway_details['castaway id'] == castaways['castaway id'].value_counts().idxmax()]
```

This gives me the wrong answer, because the person that comes out shows in the dataframe 6 times however, 3 of those times were on the same season and I don't want that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, as suggested in [ask] and [mre], please provide a representative sample of input data, and expected output, so that others may reproduce the problem. Ideally a constructor such as the output of `print(df.to_dict())`, for both `castaway` and `castaway_details`

Answer (score 0):

```
# import pandas library 
import pandas as pd

# load data 
data = [['jane', 3], ['jane', 3], ['karen', 10]]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'season'])

# drop rows which have same name and same season 
newdf = df.drop_duplicates(
    subset=['name', 'season'],
    keep='last').reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
print(newdf)
```